# developing an application in regional language/ different language

Tags: android

How can we develop any application in regional language/ different language in Android.
can we give a string's value in regional language.
do we have any keyword used in android

thank you.

Comment: do you mean create an app that shows strings in language of the user?!

Comment: @yrajabi yes, exactly. if for example i am an US based android developer and i am developing an android application for an french company, than i will have to display all the content mentioned in the application in french. then how can we do so..?? what should be the coding for that..?? please help me out of this..!!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve localization by using `strings.xml` to store the Strings, and having the translated file for the languages in the `/res/values-(local-code)` folder. Now when you reference the String in your Java code, android will automatically use the one from that locale's file, if available. If it isn't available, it defaults to the one in `/res/values/strings.xml`

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) for details.

Comment: Thank you for the right suggestion, as i am new to android so i asked this question. thank you for helping me.